# Is total angular momentum or orbital angular momentum the generator of the rotation operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, noethers-theorem

Suppose that we have a wavefunction , $\psi(\textbf{r})$. An infinitesimal rotation will induce a change in the wavefunction
\begin{align*}
    \psi\rightarrow\psi'=\hat{U}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\delta\theta)\psi(\textbf{r}')
\end{align*}
Where $\hat{U}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\delta\theta)$ is an arbitrary rotation around axis $\hat{\textbf{n}}$ by infinitesimally small angle $\delta\theta$.
The transformation must maintain the wavefunction's value if  both the wavefunction and the position are transformed
\begin{align*}
    \psi'(\textbf{r}')=\psi(\textbf{r})
\end{align*}
Where $r'$ represents the transformed coordinates, $\textbf{r}'=R_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\theta)\textbf{r}\approx\textbf{r}-\delta\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\times\textbf{r}$ for rotation matrix $R_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\theta)$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    \psi'(\textbf{r})&=\hat{U}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\delta\theta)=\psi(R^{-1}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\theta)\textbf{r})\\
    &\approx\psi(\textbf{r}-\delta\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\times\textbf{r})\\
    &=\psi(\textbf{r})-\delta\theta(\hat{\textbf{n}}\times\hat{\textbf{R}})\cdot\nabla\psi(\textbf{r})+\mathcal{O}\left((\delta\theta)^{2}\right)\\
    &=\psi(\textbf{r})-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\theta(\hat{\textbf{n}}\times\hat{\textbf{R}})\cdot\hat{\textbf{P}}\psi(\textbf{r})+\mathcal{O}\left((\delta\theta)^{2}\right)\\
    &=\psi(\textbf{r})-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\cdot(\hat{\textbf{R}}\times\hat{\textbf{P}})\psi(\textbf{r})+\mathcal{O}\left((\delta\theta)^{2}\right)\\
    &=(1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{L}})\psi(\textbf{r})+\mathcal{O}\left((\delta\theta)^{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Where $\hat{\textbf{R}}=(\hat{X},\hat{Y},\hat{Z})$ is the vector containing the position operators and
\begin{align*}
    \hat{\textbf{L}}=\hat{\textbf{R}}\times\hat{\textbf{P}}
\end{align*}
Is the (oribtal) angular momentum operator. Therefore, in the limit as $\delta\theta\rightarrow0$
\begin{align*}
    \hat{U}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\delta\theta)=(\mathbb{1}-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{L}})
\end{align*}
which can be exponentiated after using the composition property to obtain
\begin{align*}
    \hat{U}_{\hat{\textbf{n}}}(\theta)=\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\theta\hat{\textbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{L}}\right)
\end{align*}
This suggests that the orbital angular momentum operator is the generator of the rotation operator, however in Sakurai they seem to insert the total angular momentum,
\begin{align*}
    \hat{J}=\hat{L}+\hat{S}
\end{align*}
for spin angular momentum $\hat{S}$ into the rotation operator. I can't see what I've missed out in my derivation. So my question is, total angular momentum or orbital angular momentum the generator of the rotation operator in quantum mechanics? And  total angular momentum is in fact the generator (as I expect it will be) what have I missed in my derivation?

Comment: Looks like your $\psi$ is a scalar, so it describes a particle without spin. You need to use a spinor-valued wave function to describe a particle with spin $1/2$, vector-valued to describe spin $1$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the spin part, so it is correct that you do not derive $\hat{S}$ in the full angular momentum operator.

As we know spin is a basic property of particles, and a particle with spin $l$ ($l$ is a half-integer or an integer) needs $2l+1$ components to describe its wavefunction fully. Consider an electron, whose spin is ${1 \over 2}$, and it needs two functions, $\psi_{{1 \over 2}}(r)$ and $\psi_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)$, to correspondingly describe its spin-up and spin-down part. The whole wavefunction is the superposition of two, $\psi_{{1 \over 2}}(r)+\psi_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)$.

Now consider some rotation operator $\hat{U}_{\hat{n}}(\phi)$. Consider a particle with spin $l$ and one of its component $\psi_{m}(r)$ where $m \in \{l,l-1,l-2,\cdots,-l\}$, under the action of $\hat{U}(\phi)$, it transforms by the equation
$$\hat{U}_{\hat{n}}(\phi)\psi_{m}(r) = \sum_{m'}{D^{(l)}_{mm'}(\hat{n},\phi)\psi_{m'}\big((R(\hat{n},\phi))^{-1}r\big)}$$
where $D^{(l)}$ is the $2l+1$ irreducible representation of $\text{SU}(2)$ and $R \in \text{SO}(3)$ is the $3$-dimensional rotation. If you expand the equation with $\phi$ around $0$, you will get the full angular momentum operator $\hat{J}=\hat{L}+\hat{S}$ since the components of $\hat{S}$ after the multiplication of $i$ are the generators of the representation $D^{(l)}$ (the Lie algebra of $D^{(l)}$ is anti-Hermitian and $\hat{S}$ is Hermitian, and they differ by a factor of $i$). As a special case, when $l=0$, we have $\hat{J}=\hat{L}$, which is your result.

Comment: "The whole wavefunction is the superposition of two, $\psi_{{1 \over 2}}(r)+\psi_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)$." - no, that is incorrect. That particular superposition is much too restrictive.

Comment: Why is it too restrictive? I do not specify any condition on $\psi_{{1 \over 2}}(r)$ and $\psi_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)$. They only need to satisfy $\int{d^3r\psi^{\dagger}_{{1 \over 2}}(r)\psi_{{1 \over 2}}(r)}+\int{d^3r\psi^{\dagger}_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)\psi_{-{1 \over 2}}(r)}=1$.

Comment: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node47.html This website also puts down the equivalent thing.

Comment: Ah of course the spin will change after a rotation. How do you know it transforms in this way? do you have a source where they derive it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and I cannot find a source where the transformation is rigorously derived. However, it can be reasonably argued as follow: Consider the non-normalized function $\Psi_m(r;r')=\psi_m(r')\delta(r-r')$, so the wavefunction $\psi_m(r)=\int{d^3r'\Psi_m(r;r')}$. If $\Psi_m(r;r')$ transforms in the same way as the equation when being rotated, then so does $\psi_m(r)$.

Comment: So how should it transform upon rotation? Since $\Psi_m(r;r')$ can be nonzero only at $r=r'$, when we rotate $\Psi_m(r;r')$, the only nonzero value goes to the coordinate $R(\hat{n},\phi)r'$, this explains why  the rotated wavefunction $\tilde{\psi}_m(r)$ should only depend on $\psi_{m'}((R(\hat{n},\phi))^{-1}r)$'s.

Comment: But how should the functions with different $m$'s mix up after rotation? Since these $(2l+1)$ components are from the spin degree of freedom, they transform by the action of $e^{-{i \over \hbar}\hat{n}\theta \cdot \hat{S}}$, and $(e^{-{i \over \hbar}\hat{n}\theta \cdot \hat{S}})_{mm'}=D^{(l)}_{mm'}(\hat{n},\phi)$.

Comment: In some way, this argument does not really prove why the wavefunction transforms in this particular manner, it just rationalizes it and gives good predictions. More directly, if you postulate that the total angular momentum operator $\hat{J}=\hat{L}+\hat{S}$, then the wavefunction must transform in this way, and if you assume the wavefunction transofrms by the equation, then you get the total angular momentum $\hat{J}=\hat{L}+\hat{S}$.