# Where does this expression for infinitesimal rotations come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotation

In Chapter 2, page 11 of Preskill's quantum computing notes, he mentions without explaining that a counterclockwise inifinitesimal rotation by $d\theta$ about the axis $\hat{n}$ is given by

$$R(d\theta, \hat n) = I - id\theta \hat n \cdot \hat J$$
Where does $\hat J$ come from and how do we pick its components? Clearly, different choices of $J_x, J_y, J_z$ lead to different rotations. How does one know that the angular momentum will be relevant and this it appears in this form?

It just doesn't seem like we need $\hat J$ at all to describe a rotation in 3 dimensions. Given $\hat n$ and we can just look at the 2 dimensional space which is orthogonal to it and do a counterclockwise rotation of that space, so that we only need $\hat n$ and a 2 component object to describe our rotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is total angular momentum or orbital angular momentum the generator of the rotation operator in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/727655/)

Answer (score 7):

Consider a qubit system. Rotations are implemented by operators $U \in SU(2)$$^1$. The Lie group $SU(2)$ is compact and connected. Hence, the exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(2) \rightarrow SU(2)$ is surjective.

This lets us write an arbitrary rotation in the form
$$U = \exp(-i\theta X) \tag{1}$$
where $X \in \mathfrak{su}(2)$. The Pauli matrices$^2$ $\vec{\sigma}$ are a standard basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. We must divide them by $2$ to get the “right” structure constants. So, any $X \in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ can be written in the form
$$X = \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}\cdot\vec{n}. \tag{2}$$
Combining equations (1) and (2), we can write an arbitrary rotation of a single qubit as
$$U = \exp(-i\frac{\theta}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{n}).$$

Finally, let $\theta = d\theta$ be infinitesimal. Then,
$$U = \exp(-i\frac{d\theta}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{n}) = \mathbb{I} -i\frac{d\theta}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{n} +\mathcal{O}(d\theta^2)$$
by definition of matrix exponential. If you truncate the series at first order, you arrive at the appropriate expression for an infinitesimal rotation.

---

1. For sake of clarity I do not explicitly mention that we are dealing with the image of the two dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$. The two dimensional irrep because we are dealing with a single qubit system.
2. I personally take the definition of angular momentum to be the generators of rotation (equivalently, the quantity that is conserved when the Hamiltonian is invariant under rotations). Hence, by definition I identify $\vec{\sigma}$ with angular momentum. Choosing the basis of (the image of the two dimensional irreducible representation of) $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ to be the Pauli sigma matrices is indeed conventional. The convention falls out of the following. Non-relativistic physics takes place in Euclidean 3-space, $\mathbb{R}^3$. We fix an $xyz$ cartesian coordinate system so we can talk about the directions $x$, $y$, and $z$. We can then "align" the direction of the spin-z of our qubit with the direction of spatial $z$. This induces a choice of basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, i.e., the Pauli sigma matrices.

Answer (score 5):

> In Chapter 2, page 11 of Preskill's quantum computing notes, he mentions without explaining that a counterclockwise infinitesimal rotation by $d\theta$ about the axis $\hat{n}$ is given by
>
> $$R(d\theta, \hat n) = I - id\theta \hat n \cdot \hat J$$
> Where does $\hat J$ come from and how do we pick its components?

$\vec J$ is the angular momentum of the system being rotated, in units of $\hbar$. (Or rather, $\hbar \vec J$ is the angular momentum.) (But I'll just set $\hbar=1$, to make life easier.)

For example, if the system is a single spin-1/2 particle, but we ignore spatial motion, then:
$$
\vec J^{(1/2)}_{\text{no space}} = 
\hat x \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0\end{matrix}\right) 
+\hat y \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -i/2 \\ i/2 & 0\end{matrix}\right) 
+\hat z \left(\begin{matrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/2\end{matrix}\right)\;,
$$
where $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$ are unit vectors along the usual axes.

For example, if the system is a single spin-1/2 particle and we include spatial motion, then:
$$
\vec J^{(1/2)} = \left(\hat x \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0\end{matrix}\right) 
+\hat y \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -i/2 \\ i/2 & 0\end{matrix}\right) 
+\hat z \left(\begin{matrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/2\end{matrix}\right) \right)\otimes \mathbf{I}
+\mathbf{I}\otimes\vec{r} \times \vec{p}
$$

> Clearly, different choices of $J_x, J_y, J_z$ lead to different rotations. How does one know that the angular momentum will be relevant and this it appears in this form?

Yes, different systems have different angular momenta. [But, we have already agreed on the conventions to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Quantization).

One can take the angular momentum operators [as being defined as the generators of rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Angular_momentum_as_the_generator_of_rotations).

---

If you are are looking for a little more detail and precision, I would recommend checking out M. Tinkham "Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics" Chapter 5 "Full Rotation Group and Angular Momentum."

For example, Tinkham writes: "...we may *define* the x component of the *angular* momentum as the operator whose conservation follows from the invariance of the Hamiltonian under rotations about the x axis... we then obtain a definition of angular momentum in terms of infinitesimal rotation..."
$$
J_x \psi = \lim_{\delta\theta_x\to 0}i\hbar\frac{R_{\delta \theta_x} - 1}{\delta \theta_x}\psi
$$

Answer (score 3):

> Where does $\hat J$ come from

Your expression is a statement that $\hat n\cdot \mathbf J$ is the generator of infinitesimal rotations about $\hat n$. In quantum mechanics the total angular momentum operator is $\mathbf J = \mathbf L + \mathbf S$, the sum of the orbital angular momentum and spin angular momentum operators respectively, but to start we'll just look at $\mathbf L$ which is used for rotations of spatial coordinates:

From $P = -i\hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$ we know that the momentum operator is the generator of spatial translations (up to a factor of $\frac{-i}{\hbar}$), i.e. $T(\alpha)\psi(x) = \psi(x-\alpha)$ where $T(\alpha) = e^{\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}P}$. This is simply due to the general relation $e^{\alpha\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}}f(x) = f(x-\alpha)$ which can be verified by Taylor expanding both sides. More generally in 3 dimensions the translation operator in an arbitrary direction $\hat n$ is given by $T(\alpha,\hat n) = e^{\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat n \cdot \mathbf P}$ such that $T(\alpha,\hat n)\psi(\mathbf r) = \psi(\mathbf r - \alpha\hat n)$, where $\mathbf P = P_x\hat x + P_y\hat y + P_z\hat z$.

Similarly, the *angular* momentum operators are the generators of *angular* translations. The simplest example to see this is with $L_z$ since the z axis is aligned with the azimuthal axis in spherical coordinates. The vector angular momentum operator is defined as the cross product $\mathbf L = \mathbf R \times \mathbf P$ where $\mathbf R = X\hat x + Y\hat y + Z\hat z$ which gives the z component $L_z = XP_y - YP_x$. Expressing this in the position basis, $L_z = -i\hbar(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$, and using the spherical-to-cartesian coordinate transformations $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$, and $z = r\cos\theta$ to compute the Jacobian, we find that $L_z = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. Therefore $R_L(\alpha,\hat z) = e^{\alpha\frac{i}{\hbar}L_z}$ such that $R_L(\alpha,\hat z)\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = \psi(r,\theta,\phi-\alpha)$. In other words $L_z$ is the generator of rotations about the z axis.

There is for sure a more rigorous derivation than what I will write here, but I think it suffices to say that since the choice of "the z axis" for a particular spherical coordinate system is totally arbitrary and can be chosen to point in any direction, then the result that $L_z = \hat z\cdot \mathbf L$ is the generator of rotations about $\hat z$ should generalize to state that $\hat n \cdot \mathbf L$ is the generator of rotations about $\hat n$.

$$R_L(\alpha,\hat n) = e^{\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat n\cdot\mathbf L}$$

Now for $\mathbf S$. Although there is no associated translations from which we can derive that $\mathbf S$ generates rotations in a similar way to how we derived that for $\mathbf L$, we can understand that the spin state of a particle represents a direction in 3D space which can be described by angular coordinates, so the spin angular momentum operators should analogously generate rotation for those coordinates of "spin space", so to speak.

$$R_{S}(\alpha, \hat n) = e^{\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat n\cdot \mathbf S}$$

If we rotate the system as a whole then we must rotate both the positional coordinates (using $\mathbf L$) *and* the "spin coordinates" (using $\mathbf S$). More formally, the quantum state is the tensor product of the spatial state and the spin state, $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_L\rangle\otimes|\psi_S\rangle$, and the different angular momentum operators act on their respective states, i.e. $\mathbf L(|\psi_L\rangle\otimes|\psi_S\rangle) = (\mathbf L|\psi_L\rangle)\otimes|\psi_S\rangle$ and $\mathbf S(|\psi_L\rangle\otimes|\psi_S\rangle) = |\psi_L\rangle\otimes(\mathbf S|\psi_S\rangle)$. Therefore the total angular momentum operator $\mathbf J = \mathbf L + \mathbf S$ is needed to generate rotations on whole state:

$$R(\alpha,\hat n) = e^{\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat n \cdot \mathbf J}$$

To arrive at your original relation we can just expand this expression to first order for small $\alpha$:

$$R(\delta\alpha,\hat n) = e^{\delta\alpha\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat n\cdot\mathbf J} = \hat I - \delta\alpha\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat n\cdot\mathbf J  + \mathcal O(\delta\alpha^2)$$

> how do we pick its components?
> Clearly, different choices of $J_x,J_y,J_z$ lead to different
> rotations

$\mathbf J$ is a vector and so the choice of components corresponds to a choice of coordinate system (although certain coordinate systems won't have corresponding operators). However vectors are defined independently of which basis they are expanded in and furthermore the operator $\hat n \cdot \mathbf J$ is the result of a dot product and is a coordinate independent quantity. Therefore the expression for the rotation operator doesn't depend on your choice of components for expressing $\mathbf J$.

> It just doesn't seem like we need $\hat J$ at all to describe a rotation in
> 3 dimensions. Given $\hat n$ and we can just look at the 2 dimensional
> space which is orthogonal to it and do a counterclockwise rotation of
> that space, so that we only need $\hat n$ and a 2 component object to
> describe our rotation.

It is true that to describe a rotation by an angle all we need is an oriented plane (which is a 2D object like you said), which in 3D space is equivalent to specifying a vector to represent the plane which it is normal to and to represent the angle of rotation with its magnitude. However in 3D space there are 3 linearly independent planes of rotation ($xy,yz$, and $zx$) so we need 3 linearly independent angular momentum operators to generate rotations in each.

That being said, a general rotation of a 3D object from one orientation to another is uniquely specified by a sequence of 3 rotations and in fact only requires 2 independent axes to perform the rotations around. Common rotation conventions include ZYZ, ZXZ, XYX, etc. which specify a sequence with 3 angles $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ to rotate by, in order, about those respective axes. In the case of ZYZ for example, the rotation operator would be

$$R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = e^{-\gamma\frac{iJ_z}{\hbar}}e^{-\beta\frac{iJ_y}{\hbar}}e^{-\gamma\frac{iJ_z}{\hbar}}$$

which only uses $J_y$ and $J_z$.